# Passing and incrementing Java variables across methods

Tags: java, android, variables, int, increment

EDIT: I changed `setChoice(i++)` to `setChoice(++i)`. It works.

I want to make a drag/drop activity that loads three TextViews to be dragged to three ImageViews, like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOKnU.png. I want to make 5 levels where the text changes, the pictures won't.

So I have an activity that has a main method(`onCreate`), `onLongClickListener`, `onDragListener`, a method to set three TextViews(`setChoice(int i)`), and a method to check the values of the TextViews(`checkAll`).

In `public class` I declare a 2d string[], `choice`, and an int `i`, along with the TextViews and ImageViews.

int `i` is what this question is about. In `onCreate` I initialize everything and:

```
    i = 0;
    setChoice(i);
```

`setChoice` checks the value of `i`, if it's less than 5 it matches the TextViews randomly to 1,2,3 and sets the text from the 2d[]:

```
    int num = (int)(Math.random()*3);
    tvOne.setText(choice[i][num]);

    int num2 = (int)(Math.random()*3);
    if(!(num == num2)){
        tvTwo.setText(choice[i][num2]);
    }else{
        do{
            num2 = (int)(Math.random()*3);
        }while(num == num2); 
        tvTwo.setText(choice[i][num2]);
    }
```

And then `return`.

At this point, the TextViews are filled with `choice[0][]`, and the user should drag the words "Truck", "Helicopter", and "Boat" to the images. Each `onDrag` compares the TextView string to a string from `choice[][]`, which I get like this:

```
String choiceOne = choice[i][0];
```

If the strings match, the TextView text gets changed to "Correct". Each time a TextView is changed to "Correct" I call `checkAll`.

`checkAll` compares all three TextViews to the string "Correct". If not all match, it returns, otherwise I want to call `setChoice(i++)` and load the next row from `choice[][]` (i.e. `choice[1][]`).

I guess the `i` that I pass from `checkAll()`, which should be one higher, isn't incremented, because the TextViews are filled with `chioce[0][]` again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: primitive types are passed by value. So the `i` in one method is not the same as the `i` in another if passed as parameter, but a copy. Could this be your problem? (It's difficult to understand, posting more code would be easier)

Comment: Yeah, sounds like my problem, I'm trying to pass them as parameters. I'd post more code if I knew what more would help.